# Jenkins Monitoring and Analytics

Tags: jenkins

What is the best tool to have Jenkins Monitoring tools for analytics?

I know some methods we can use however, Please share some use case

```
Proactive Issue Detection:
    Jenkins monitoring allows for the early detection of potential issues, preventing them from escalating into critical problems within the CI/CD pipeline.
Optimizing Resource Utilization:
    By monitoring resource usage, teams can identify bottlenecks, optimize resource allocation, and ensure efficient utilization of computing resources.
Performance Metrics:
    Monitoring provides valuable insights into the performance of Jenkins jobs, helping teams optimize build times and enhance overall pipeline efficiency.
```

Got above from [Jenkins monitoring](https://testertechie.com/jenkins-monitoring-and-analytics/)